# Using RegEx to parse all cell references within a formula (precedents) in google sheets script

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

Assuming a cell contains the following formula:

```
 =sum(G1:H1)+$G$1+G1 +sum(G$1:$H$1)
```

I want to parse all addresses in the formula using regex.

**Regex:**

```
(\$?\w+\$?\d+)(:(\$?\w+\$?\d+))?
```

**First group**
`(\$?\w+\$?\d+)` is a sequence of:

`\$?` - zero or one $ - for absolute column

`\w+` - one or more letters (in case cell column is more than one letter (AA)

`\$?` - zero or one $ - for absolute row

`\d+` - one or more digits

**Second Group**
`(:(\$?\w+\$?\d+))?` is basically the same like the first group preceding by `:` (in case it is a range) ending with `?` to indicate zero or one.

**Expected Result:**

> [G1:H1,$G$1,G1,G$1:$H1$1]

**Actual Result:**

> [G1:H1, G1, :H1, H1]

this is the code I use:

```
var formulaStr  = "sum(G1:H1)+$G$1+G1 +sum(G$1:$H$1)";
  // Regex pattern including escape character for all $ signs
  var rg2 = "(\\$?\\w+\\$?\\d+)(:(\\$?\\w+\\$?\\d+))?";
  var res = formulaStr.match(rg2);
  
  
  Logger.log(formulaStr);
  Logger.log(rg2);
  Logger.log(res);
```

**output:**

> sum(G1:H1)+$G$1+G1 +sum(G$1:$H$1)

> ($?\w+$?\d+)(:($?\w+$?\d+))?

> [G1:H1, G1, :H1, H1]

I tried this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/yECczt/1).
Although I don't fully understand the match info displayed, it looks OK to me as it states "4 matches".

Two questions:

Why the absolute addresses (say $G$1) do not match?

Why `:H1` is returned. It starts with a colon, whereas all first group is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Regex. Take into account that in case you use more Columns (for example AA2, DB43, etc) the query would need to change.

`[A-Z]\d+` *All characters from A to Z `[A-Z]` plus a digit `\d` that can match 1 or more `+`*

Implemented to the code:

```
var formulaText = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell().getFormula();
var cells = formulaText.match(/[A-Z]\d+/g);
```

The `g` is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

**Example:**

`=A1/B1 + C3 = 0.5`

**Result:**

`A1,B1,C3`

---

## References:

- [match method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)
- [Regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)
- [Cool site to test Regex](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Using regex is what I was thinking about, although it is not that simple for the general case. I rephrased the question. Ignoring for now with the cases of NamedRange or reference to another sheet.